# Multiple bar widths in Chart.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to have different bar widths for different datasets? I have a couple datasets in one stack, and another dataset in its own stack. The single dataset should be narrower than the other stack

[Example](http://codepen.io/MalikDrako/pen/YZNVdv). Here I duplicated the left stack, resulting in it being twice the width of the right stack. This breaks certain effects, including nonzero borders

```
var data = {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "d1",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(182,127,0,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(117,61,41,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [42, 78, 64, 90, 97],
      stack: "s1"
    },
    {
      label: "d2",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(71,161,65,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(36,93,56,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [27, 63, 46, 64, 43],
      stack: "s1"
    },
    {
      label: "d3",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,141,106,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(99,60,32,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [18, 50, 23, 83, 35],
      stack: "s1"
    },
    {
      label: "d1",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(182,127,0,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(117,61,41,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [42, 78, 64, 90, 97],
      stack: "s1b"
    },
    {
      label: "d2",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(71,161,65,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(36,93,56,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [27, 63, 46, 64, 43],
      stack: "s1b"
    },
    {
      label: "d3",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,141,106,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(99,60,32,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [18, 50, 23, 83, 35],
      stack: "s1b"
    },
    {
      label: "d4",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(160,160,160,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(60,60,60,1)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [152, 141, 170, 194, 128],
      stack: "s2",
      barPercentage: 0.3
    }
  ]
};
var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      categoryPercentage: 0.6,
      barPercentage: 1
    }]
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
};

var barChart = new Chart($("#myChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is possible to do in chart.js, but the solution is a bit "hackish".  The gist of it is that you can create a 2nd x axis scale and set the `barThickness` property to a value smaller than your other axis.  Then you assign your dataset to this access and finally, set the scale display to false.

You end up with some datasets on 1 axis and another dataset on a different hidden axis.  Everything else still works (no breaking effects like you mentioned in your question).

Here is what your options would look like.

```
var options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      categoryPercentage: 0.6,
      barPercentage: 1,
    }, {
      id: 'x-axis-2',
      type: 'category',
      display: false,
      categoryPercentage: 0.6,
      barPercentage: 1,
      barThickness: 20,
      gridLines: {
        offsetGridLines: true
      }
    }],
  },
  legend: {
    display: false
  }
};
```

You have to make sure you add `xAxisID: 'x-axis-2'` to whichever dataset you want to bind to the new axis.

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/vxWyPY) demonstrating all of this.

You can even do this for a horizontal bar chart by changing the scales around.  See this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/RpxbjO) showing this.

Comment: Looks like pretty much what I need, but does it work for horizontal bar charts? I tried switching your example, but the 2nd axis no longer displayed http://codepen.io/MalikDrako/pen/RpjLRd?editors=0010 It also looks like the axes are swapped in some places, but not others - tried setting tye type to logarighmic for the y axis but it seemed to set it for the vertical axis.

Answer (score 0):

The chart.js documentation shows a `barThickness` attribute [available in the options for a chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options), but no such option available [at the data set level](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-dataset-structure). I think you may be out of luck unless you want to create your own custom chart type.